# Android Room cascade delete for a one to many relationship

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

Say I have two entities, Workout and Exercise and a one to many relationship exists between Workout (one) and Exercise (many). The entities are setup like this

Workout Entity:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "workouts",
    indices = [Index("startDate")]
)
data class Workout(
    @PrimaryKey
    val startDate: String,

    val workoutName: String
)
```

Exercise Entity:

```
@Entity
data class Exercise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val exerciseId: Long = 0,

    val workoutId: String,

    val name: String
)
```

Workout with Exercises:

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Workout::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("startDate"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("workoutId"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Exercise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val exerciseId: Long = 0,

    val workoutId: String,

    val name: String
)
```

This is how I get the exercises related to a workout:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM workouts WHERE startDate = :startDate")
suspend fun getWorkoutWithExercises(startDate: String): WorkoutWithExercises
```

So my question is, if the workout instance containing exercises is deleted, will the related exercises also be deleted? If not, how would this be accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exercises will also be deleted as you have created a `Foreign Key` for the table Exercise.